# Edit uploaded image with Intervention

Tags: php, image, function, laravel, upload

I am adding the ability to edit an image that is already uploaded on a shopping cart app I am building. I am able to upload an image fine. I am also able to edit every field perfectly except for the image file upload.

I have tried using the same code I have in the upload function to basically upload another image over the existing one but it does not work and throws an error

```
Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on a non-object
```

I am using the Laravel framework with intervention and went to the main site of intervention and it does not show an update or edit method. It just shows a delete method.

I need some help in figuring out how to update the image in my postEdit function.

I really have tried everything I know and have researched this with google and cannot figure this out.

My problem lies in this line of code:

```
File::update('public/'.$product->image);
```

Thank you for the right direction.

Here is the image upload function (which works perfect)

```
public function postCreate() {
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Product::$rules);

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        $product = new Product;
        $product->category_id = Input::get('category_id');
        $product->title = Input::get('title');
        $product->description = Input::get('description');
        $product->price = Input::get('price');

        $image = Input::file('image');
        $filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = public_path('img/products/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(468, 249)->save($path);
        $product->image = 'img/products/'.$filename;
        $product->save();

        return Redirect::to('admin/products/index')
            ->with('message', 'Product Created');
    }

    return Redirect::to('admin/products/index')
        ->with('message', 'Something went wrong')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
```

Here is the edit image upload function which I cannot get to work.

```
public function postEdit() {
    $product = Product::find(Input::get('id'));


    if ($product) {
        File::update('public/'.$product->image);
        $product->update(Input::all());
        return Redirect::to('admin/products/index')
        ->with('message', 'Product Updated');
    }

    return Redirect::to('admin/products/index')
        ->with('message', 'Something went wrong, please try again');
}
```

Comment: can anyone please answer this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First there is no method for the `File` facade called update.

You have to reprocess the image to update it.

Secondly, the error is being thrown from the upload. This could be because the image is not being sent through the form properly.

Make sure you have files attribute on your form open.

```
{{ Form::open(array('route'=> array('aroute'),'method' => 'post', 'files' => true)) }}
```

If your file is still not being sent check your php.ini setting as the file size of the image could be greater of that set in the `post_max_size` or `upload_max_filesize` to a value greater than that size.

Also the change the line;

```
$path = public_path('img/products/' . $filename);
```

to

```
$path = public_path() . 'img/products/' . $filename;
```

And to edit the image with intervention you need to save the file.

Use;

```
$image->move($path);
```

then you can do;

```
Image::make($path)->resize(468, 249)->save($path);
```

Comment: You are right. Sorry for the delay. I figured it out with the help from a friend. Here is what I did. First set the 'files'=>true just like you said. Second, move the  $product->update(Input::all()); below the product image and make sure that the image attributes are excluded  when updated because the image property is already set.

Comment: Here is the completed part http://laravel.io/forum/06-30-2014-update-image-using-intervention  It all came down to common sense.